# How to calculate household size?

Tags: usa, immigration, financial

My sister has 4 persons in her household, and she is sponsoring my wife (which makes it 5). She has declared an income of about 35k last year, which is not enough for a household of 5, but is enough for a household of 4. And one of her children was born after tax filing. Is it OK to count her household size without that child?

Comment: The child exists, she's supporting it.  It's not certain they would catch it but they might and she (and you) wouldn't want that!

Comment: Assuming she is not self-employed, it's not her income last year that matters -- it is her *current* (i.e. right now) income that matters.

Comment: @user102008 She is self-employed

Comment: Your sister is sponsoring your wife, so both will probably have to make statements to the immigration authorities about the sister's household. Your question really asks if it's OK for them to lie. As @LorenPechtel observes above: if the authorities discover this falsehood, then both your sister and your wife will have black marks in the authority's books, and future applications will probably be denied because they were willfully untruthful in this one.

Comment: @user102008 They want three years of tax returns.  That's much more credible than declared self-employment income.  (And beware, they are a bit math challenged.  It took a detailed explanation of how the math worked along with our third submission before they accepted it--they were blindly rejecting it because the stated number didn't appear on the tax form.)

Comment: @David Actually I do not want to lie. The income on the tax report was filed last year and she had one child. Current income may be increased and is not clear until the end of the year and tax filing.
Is it OK to include checking account balance to cover the minimum income?

Comment: @user102008 We are putting the annual income based on tax report.

Comment: @Polymorphic: For self-employed people, they should report their income as listed on last year's taxes. (For non-self-employed people, they should use their current salary, which may not be related to the income on last year's taxes; but self-employed people don't have that.) She can use assets to cover the deficiency in income, but $5 of assets counts for $1 of income.